# Getting error RSolve::dsfun

Tags: warning-messages, recursion

I an trying to solve a recursive formula and find the explicit representation of $a$.

$a_0 = 1$

$a_{n+1} = 3 \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} a_i$

When I evaluate

```
RSolve[{a[n] == 3 Sum[a[i], {i, 0, n }], a[0] == 1}, a[n], n]
```

the output is

> RSolve: 2 a[-1 + n] cannot be used as a function.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe you should do `Clear[a, n]` and try again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `a[n]` the upper bound of the summation should be `n-1`

```
Clear[a]

eqns = {a[n] == 3 Sum[a[i], {i, 0, n - 1}], a[0] == 1};

a[n_] = a[n] /. RSolve[eqns, a[n], n][[1]]
```

[image]

```
a[0]

(* 1 *)

And @@ Table[a[n] == 3 Sum[a[i], {i, 0, n - 1}], {n, 1, 50}]

(* True *)
```

Alternatively, the LHS should be `a[n+1]`

```
Clear[a]

eqns = {a[n + 1] == 3 Sum[a[i], {i, 0, n}], a[0] == 1};

a[n_] = a[n] /. RSolve[eqns, a[n], n][[1]]
```

[image]

```
a[0]

(* 1 *)

And @@ Table[a[n+1] == 3 Sum[a[i], {i, 0, n}], {n, 1, 50}]

(* True *)
```